# Texmaker: PDF does not update after compiling

Tags: texmaker

When I use the pdf view, I want to change my compile and see how it work, but I press the pdf view, it doesn't update my change of compile, it stays the same, how can  I fix it? Many thanks!

Comment: **(1)** Welcome. **(2)** I changed your titel to something more meaningful. **(3)** I changed the `tag` to something more meaningful (the tag is now `texmaker` and ntr `errors`). **(4)** For the next question, consider to read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: If you have an error in your code but the compilation ended without fatal error, you need to manually push on "view pdf".

Comment: I have the same problem. When I run the texmaker the pdf does not update. I see the old pdf. I do not know very much about configure the texmaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make sure, that you choose `Quick Build` (1st screenshot, top area / left of the center).
- In the options, make sure that you have `+ View PDF` (2nd screenshot, actually, there is always `+ View PDF`).

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks! it's really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

This can also be caused by *not actually having LaTeX installed*. I forgot to do this on a fresh machine right now, and TexMaker will silently fail while appearing to have processed the document. Remember to install a Tex distribution!